# Parsing all CSV files in a directory, line by line

Tags: shell, unix, csv, awk

I have a number of CSV files, all with the same structure, in one directory.
Now being said that, i would like to parse the lines and count how many lines have column 5 in a predefined values array `a = [A, B, C, D]`.

Im pretty unexperienced with shell scripting so, is `awk` the way to do this, or should i go for a `python` script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this awk one liner:

```
awk '$5 ~ /^(A|B|C|D)$/' *.csv
```

It iterates over all lines of all `.csv` files in the current directory and checks if the 5th column (`$5`) matches (`~`) the pattern `^(A|B|C|D)$`. If the line matches the pattern awk will print the whole line. We have not specified an action but printing the whole line is awk's default action.

The pattern:

`^` matches the begin of the string and `$` matches the end of the string. Therefore the pattern matches from beginning to the end. `(A|B|C|D)` represents a choise of possible values, like a logical `OR` operation in other programming languages. I've used the single characters `A,B,C,D` as in your question but you are free to use something like `(foo|bar|hello|world)`.

Comment: Great answer, matched exactly my needs! Thanks!

Comment: Counting the lines can be done in awk, I prefer appending `| wc -l`.

Answer (score 2):

The other currently posted answer does a RE comparison which is almost certainly not what you really are looking for (try it if one of your desired values is `.*`).

This does a string comparison:

```
awk '
BEGIN{ split("A B C D",tmp); for (i in tmp) a[tmp[i]] }
$5 in a { cnt++ }
END { print cnt+0 }
' file
```